# Nashorn alternative for Java 11

Tags: java, nashorn, scriptengine, javascript-engine, graalvm

I am using the Nashorn JavaScript Engine in Java 11 which works fine except it will be deprecated soon. I have tried GraalVM which I find quite worse as it takes 13-14 seconds to execute a simple expression (e.g. 2+3). Is there any other alternative that I could use or should I try GraalVM with some other approach (if there is any)?

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("javascript");
engine.eval("2+3");
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you run your code to make it take 13s? That exact code takes under a second on my machine using GraalVM.

Comment: Meta comment.  The time it took for the answers to this question to become out-of-date clearly illustrates the problem with "recommendation" Q&A's!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Rhino as replacement](https://jaxenter.com/nashorn-deprecation-interview-caldwell-146951.html)

> Rhino still is being maintained as an open-source project and so has a history of community involvement. For some uses, it’s clearly superior because of its faster startup time.

Comment: That's a rather old post (from July 2018) to cite as relevant. GraalVM 19.0.0 (no release candidate mentioned) was released in May 2019.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjdk.nashorn/nashorn-core Apr 23, 2022

Answer (score 5):

***Update (June 2022):***

As of 2022, it seems J2V8 is also poorly maintained.

Better set your sights on [Javet](https://github.com/caoccao/Javet/)

---

If someone still finds this question relevant, a viable, still actively maintained alternative to Nashorn/Rhino script engines is the [J2V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8) binding for the JVM.

Artifacts can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eclipsesource.j2v8/j2v8) (be sure to use this link to get updated releases)

Multi-platform support is builtin via JNI

Though its mechanics are a bit different than those of the `ScriptEngine` API, performance is (as expected) better. and you don't have to deal with weird side effects like unintended class-loading caused by misuse of the API.

I have successfully used it myself in the past.